# Joomla component router

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to follow the instructions on this docs page, but I seem to be missing something:
https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

The URI that needs to be corrected is: index.php?com_component&view=legal&page=customermasteragreement

It seems like the routing function should be simple, but the page is just displaying default instead of the sub-view.

Here's my current code:

```
function ComponentBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();
        if (isset($query['view'])) {
            $segments[] = $query['view'];
            unset($query['view']);
       }
        if (isset($query['page'])) {
            $segments[] = $query['page'];
            unset($query['page']);
    }

    return $segments;
}

function ComponentParseRoute($segments)
{
       $vars = array();
       switch($segments[0])
       {
               case 'legal':
                       $vars['view'] = 'legal';
                       break;
               case 'customermasteragreement':
                       $vars['page'] = 'customermasteragreement';
                       break;

       }

       return $vars;
}
```

**Update**
This code works to display the subpage, but it gives me a URI like: legal-agreements/legal?page=customermasteragreement

```
class ComponentRouter extends JComponentRouterBase {

    public function build(&$query) {
        $segments = array();
        $view = null;

        if (isset($query['view'])) {
            $segments[] = $query['view'];
            $view = $query['view'];

            unset($query['view']);
        }

        if (isset($query['id'])) {
            if ($view !== null) {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
            } else {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
            }

            unset($query['id']);
        }

        return $segments;
    }


    public function parse(&$segments) {

        $vars = array();

        // View is always the first element of the array
        $vars['view'] = array_shift($segments);

        return $vars;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If it helps, here's my model and views

models/legal.php

```
// import Joomla modelitem library
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');

class ComponentModelLegal extends JModelItem {
    public function __construct($config = array())
            {
       JLoader::register('ComponentHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/helpers/component.php');
       parent::__construct($config);
            }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLegal() {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $page = $app->input->get('page', '', 'STRING');

        if ($page) {
            ComponentHelper::add('type', $page);   //This is an API request to an external service, returning JSON formatted data
            $legal = ComponentHelper::getData('commons/legal-agreements.json', TRUE);


            if (isset($legal[0]['status'])) {
                JError::raiseError(400, $legal[0]['ERROR']);
                return false;
            } else {
                if (!isset($this->legal)) {
                    $this->legal = $legal;
                }
                return $this->legal;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

views/legal/view.html.php

```
class ComponentViewLegal extends JViewLegacy {
    function display($tpl = null) {
        // Assign data to the view
        $this->legal = $this->get('legal');

        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
            JLog::add(implode('<br />', $errors), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');
            return false;
        }

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

views/legal/tmpl/default.php

```
$page = JRequest::getVar('page');
$pages = array(
    'resellermasteragreement',
    'customermasteragreement',
    'resellerdomainagreement',
    'customerdomainagreement',
    'resellerwebserviceagreement',
    'customerwebserviceagreement',
    'resellerdigicertagreement',
    'customerdigicertagreement',
    'registraragreement',
    'customerhostingproductagreement',
    'resellerhostingproductagreement'
);

    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php 
        echo in_array($page, $pages) ? $this->loadTemplate('legal') : $this->loadTemplate('home');
        ?>
    </div>
```

views/legal/tmpl/default_legal.php

```
$page = JRequest::getVar('page');

echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($this->legal[$page]['defaultagreement'], ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"));
?>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo JROUTE::_("index.php?option=com_component&view=legal"); ?>">Back</a>
```

**EDIT 3**
This works because I wasn't navigating directly to the page from a menu item.  There's a top level menu, then a page a links to the agreements.  I have a hidden menu to each item, but that wasn't the link I followed.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$customermaster = $app->getItems( 'link', 'index.php?option=com_component&view=legal&page=customermasteragreement', true );
JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid='.$customermaster->id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one `view` but you're not actually set the `page` argument correctly when you catch a `view` argument, but you treat `page` as some king of another view. Can you please try this and check if it works:

```
function [componentname]ParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();
    switch($segments[0])
    {
        case 'legal':
            $vars['view'] = 'legal';
            $vars['page'] = $segments[1];
            break;
    }

    return $vars;
}
```

Also the functions `ComponentBuildRoute`, `ComponentParseRoute` must have your components name instead of `Component` at the beginning.

**EDIT**

`[componentname]BuildRoute` and `[componentname]ParseRoute` are deprecated, you should stick the the class that extends `JComponentRouterBase` as you have it in your updated second example. Try this one here and see if it works:

```
class ComponentRouter extends JComponentRouterBase {

    public function build(&$query) {
        $segments = array();
        $view = null;

        if (isset($query['view'])) {
            $segments[] = $query['view'];
            $view = $query['view'];

            unset($query['view']);
        }

        if (isset($query['page'])) {
            $segments[] = $query['page'];
            unset($query['page']);
        }

        return $segments;
    }

    public function parse(&$segments) {

        $vars = array();

        // View is always the first element of the array
        $vars['view'] = array_shift($segments);
        if(count($segments) > 0)
            $vars['page'] = array_shift($segments);

        return $vars;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have a test Joomla 3 site with a simple component named `Ola`.

Non SEO component URL: http://j3.dev.lytrax.net/index.php?option=com_ola&page=test_page&view=ola

URL generated by `JRoute` before Router class added to `router.php`: http://j3.dev.lytrax.net/index.php/component/ola/?page=test_page&view=ola

SEO URL returned by `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_ola&page=test_page&view=ola');` after creating `router.php` and used the Router class above: http://j3.dev.lytrax.net/index.php/component/ola/ola/test_page

If you visit the links, you'll see that all are working and you can even see the `page`, `view` and `JRoute` results of the calling component `Ola`.

Comment: Unless my component's name is "component".  :)

Comment: @JamesShaver of course. I just wrote this to clarify that the correct name needs to be at the beginning of the class/functions. Please try my updated class and see if it works as you want.

Comment: Now it's giving a 404 error: View not found [name, type, prefix]: view, html, componentView.

Comment: It's working for me. I have created a test component named `Ola` and added a simple default view, a page parameter and the route exactly as i have it in my answer. Have you included `index.php` to test the SEO URL?

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as it seems that my next issues are unrelated to the router.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Unless I've completely misunderstood Joomla (I've been developing with it for four five years now), there is no "sub-view" concept implemented.  Trying to use the idea is what's getting you into trouble I think.

I'm astounded that the idea of using a visual debugger is so unpopular.
Get yourself something like Netbeans (there are others too), set up a local web and database server, and watch the code run.  Very (well, relatively very) quickly you'll start to understand how the structure hangs together.

You may put code in your view that picks up the extra params you've set and displays or hides things accordingly, but there is no "sub-view".

Comment: Actually I do use NetBeans, as well as PHPStorm and Visual Studio Code. A subview in this case is simply the normal view with a switch on JRequest::getVar('page'). Loading another file from there is simply looking for it as $this->loadTemplate('legal')

Comment: Take a look at com_content, or com_newsfeeds.  They both have the same concepts.